# Django / GraphQL -- 2 types have fields that are referencing each other causes a crash

Tags: python, django, graphql

I have 2 graphql types that each have fields that refer to the other. There is an error because one of the types has not been declared when the first one is read. The issue is that the type should be instantiated before using it in a field. But since the two types refer to each other, One is always being referred to before it has been instantiated.

Any ideas on how to solve?

Here is a link to the parts of the code that are relevant:
https://gist.github.com/olivermontalbano/ce8db9fd62619b983ed68b6933ff7e64